# Вопрос по условиям в jquery (js)

Tags: javascript, jquery

Пытаюсь написать функцицию с радиокнопками, но почему-то не работает скрипт.

```
    <input type="radio" name="test" class="input_1">
    <input type="radio" name="test" class="input_2">
    <span class="test_1"></span>
```

Примерно вот так:

```
    <script>
        $('input.input_1').change(function(){
            if( $('.input_1').change ) {
              $('span.test_1').addClass('style_1');
            } else {
                   $('span.test_1').text('style_2');
                   }
          });
    </script>
```

В чем моя ошибка?

Comment: что именно не работает? в примере разметки нигде не указан элемент с классом `input_1`

Comment: Спасибо, поправил.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`input type="radio"` - работает как кнопка, поэтому будем использовать событие `click`. Проверка `if( $('.input_1').change )` не имеет смысла, так как проверяет наличие метода `change` у jQuery-евской обертки и всегда возвращает `true`.

Похоже, Вам нужно что-то типа:

```js
$('input[name="test"]').click(function(){
  $('input[name="test"]').each(function(){
    $('span.test_1').removeClass($(this).data("spanclass"));
  });
  $('span.test_1').text($(this).data("spanclass"));
  $('span.test_1').addClass($(this).data("spanclass"));
});
```

```css
.style_1{ color:red; }
.style_2{ color:green; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="radio" name="test" class="input_1" data-spanclass="style_1">
<input type="radio" name="test" class="input_2" data-spanclass="style_2">
<span class="test_1"></span>
```

Comment: и где же объяснения?

Comment: @Grundy минуту.